# How to change input value when click on another input box in React

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React. I am trying to select country value in input box and handlechange event will target the country code and value will select automatically. I did't add functions handlechange and handleClick here as they were not working. Also I am getting different input box for each field. How to get only one input box with dropdown list?

```
export default class Api extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      
          this.state = {
            country: [],
            countryCode:''
          };
        }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.warn(result);
        this.setState({ country: result });
        console.log("i am in console");
      });
  }

 this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center"> Api</h1>
        <h2> country details</h2>
        <div>
          {this.state.country.map((countries, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <label>Select Country</label>
                <select>
                    <option  onClick={this.handleClick}> {countries.name}</option>
                    </select>
               
              <label>Country Code: </label><input type="text" className="m-5" value={countries.callingCodes} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /> 
            
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: because of the input is in map function, so that it will generate many input boxes

Comment: Can I use forEach instead of map ?

Comment: @Ash did you have chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with my changes [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-wind-j08hc?file=/src/App.js).

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Api extends Component {
  state = {
    countries: [],
    countryName: "",
    countryCode: ""
  };

  handleCountryPick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const country = this.state.countries.find(
      (country) => country.name === event.target.value
    );
    this.setState({
      countryCode: country.callingCodes,
      countryName: country.name
    });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");
    const countries = await response.json();
    this.setState({ countries: countries });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center">Api</h1>
        <h2>country details</h2>
        <CountrySelector
          countries={this.state.countries}
          countryName={this.state.countryName}
          onCountryPickHandler={this.handleCountryPick}
        />
        <CountryCodeInput countryCode={this.state.countryCode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CountrySelector = ({ countryName, countries, onCountryPickHandler }) => {
  const options = countries.map((country) => (
    <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
      {country.name}
    </option>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={countryName || "none"} onChange={onCountryPickHandler}>
        {options}
        <option value="none">None</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const CountryCodeInput = ({ countryCode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Country Code: </label>
      <input type="text" value={countryCode} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is what you need to learn to be able to implement from scratch:

1. data binding is one-way, from parent to child, that is why you need to keep your handler (callback) `handleCountryPick` in the parent that keeps the state `countries`, `countryName`, `countryCode`.
2. time when updates happen and which components know what at which moment.

[image: Sequence UML Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what's inside the `Array.map()`
(I renamed your `state.country` to `state.countries` as it is an array.)

```js
  handleCountrySelectChange(e) {
    const selectedCountry = e.target.value
    // ...
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    const countryCode = e.target.value
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center">Api</h1>
      <h2>country details</h2>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Select Country</label>
          <select onChange={this.handleCountrySelectChange}>
            {this.state.countries.map(country => (
              <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
                {country.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <label>Country Code: </label>
          <input type="text" className="m-5" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I edited the code. Can you please tell me how to get country code in handleInputChange() ?

Comment: Your edit was rejected. Please don't edit an answer for asking a new question. You can create a JS Fiddle or Code Sandbox example of a follow-up question and ask in the comment. From your edit I could not understand what you're struggling with. Doesn't `e.target.value` work for you?